# How Can I Copy Text From Hidden Textarea to Clipboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a hidden text area like this with some values set:

```
<textarea style="display: none;" id="element_html"></textarea>
```

On click of a button, I try to copy its content to clipboard using this JS code:

```
$('#element_html').select();
document.execCommand('copy');
```

It works only if the text area is visible. How can I copy the hidden text area content to clipboard?

Comment: Have you tried `height: 0; visibility: hidden; width: 0;` or absolutely positioning the textarea off the screen?

Comment: I fail to see a connection between `performance` tag and this question. Did you add it because you app does not *"perform"*?

Comment: @fubar The text cannot be copied if `visibility` is set to `hidden` or if `display` is set to `none`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is also true for a textarea element that is marked as disabled. You need to remove the disabled attribute (even if temporarily) before trying to copy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
opacity: .01;
```

does the job. You should combine it with:

```
height:0;
position:absolute;
z-index: -1;
```

Do not use `pointer-events:none;` as it will stop `.select()` from working, as well.

```js
function copyContents() {
  $('#element_html').select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```css
#element_html {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .01;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="element_html">Which textarea?</textarea>
<button onclick="copyContents()">Copy</button>

<input type="text" placeholder="Paste it here...">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a temporary input element that is appended to the body, set it its value to the textarea's content and then use it for the copy function. Then you remove it from the dom. This will work - irrespective of the display state of the text area.

Note that I did not create this method - I got it from somewhere (possibly another SO answer) and have used it since in a number of instances.

```js
function copyContents() {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  var content = $('#element_html').text();
  
 $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(content).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

```css
#element_html {
display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="element_html">Hidden textarea content</textarea>
<button onclick="copyContents()">Click to copy</button>

<input type="text" placeholder="Paste here">
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to add an extra form element to DOM if they already have one? If you really want to use javascript, change the textarea's `style` attributes so it becomes VisiblePainted (and `.select()`-able), get the contents and, if required, change it back to not painted. Besides, depending on browser, device and length of textarea contents, the page might flicker during this gimmick. I advise against this technique. It triggers repaint on the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since the textarea has its display property set to `none`, its content can not be selected. You can absolutely position the textarea to the left with `position: absolute` and `left: -9999px`. You should also add `z-index: -9999` so it will always be placed under other elements (unless they have a lower z-index).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;" id="element_html">Text inside textarea</textarea>
<button onClick="copy()">
Copy
</button>
<p/>
<textarea placeholder="Paste text here..."></textarea>
<script>
function copy(){
$('#element_html').select();
document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Following codes worked for my problem. paste the js code inside your script tag/file.also add the css style to hide the textarea. Also, I found the following ideas through stackoverflow forum so all credit to those folks.

HTML code:

```js
function cpy(n)
{
var id=n;
var txt=document.getElementById(id);
txt.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
};
```

```css
  /* The Following Code is to Hide textarea from The user view area */
    textarea{
         opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
  pointer-events: none;
    }
```

```html
<!-- readonly attribute is used because i found that in mobile devices, keyboard poped-up while i clicked the button to copy text-->

<textarea id="c1" readonly>
This is a text from textarea One.
</textarea><br>
<!--The cpy(this.id) passes button id to js function-->
<button id="c1" onclick="cpy(this.id)">Copy</button>
<input type=text placeholder="Paste Here to test">
```